# How to save data to the database when the user registers, ie how to remember the data with which he registered in the database?

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor

I'm doing this in Blazor (c #). 
The following is the code that has been generated so far:

User.cs:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
   [Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
   public int UserId { get; set; }

   [Display(Name = "UserName")]
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "UserName is required.")]
   public string UserName { get; set; }

   [Display(Name = "Password")]
   [Required]
   [MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = "password must be atleast 8 characters")]
   [DataType(DataType.Password)]
   public string Password { get; set; }

   [Display(Name = "Email")]
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
   public string Email { get; set; }

   [Display(Name = "Company")]
   [StringLength(255)]
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company is required.")]
   [Remote("doesCompanyExist", "Company", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Company already exists. Please enter a different company.")]
   public string Company { get; set; }

   public User GetRegisteredUser()
   {
       return new User
       {
           UserName = UserName,
           Password = Password,
           Email = Email,
           Company = Company,

       };
   }     
}
```

Register.razor:

```
@page "/register"

@using TestBlazor.Models

<br /> <br />

<h3><b>Register</b></h3> <br />

<EditForm class="needs-validation" Model="@_user"
OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit"
OnInvalidSubmit="@HandleInvalidSubmit">
<div class="alert @StatusClass">@StatusMessage</div>
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
<ValidationSummary />
<div class="form-group">
   <p><b>User name</b></p>
   <input id="username" class="solid" name="username" placeholder="Your username.." @bind-value="_user.UserName" />
   <ValidationMessage For="@(() => @_user.UserName)"></ValidationMessage>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <p><b>Password</b></p>
   <input type="password" class="solid" id="password" placeholder="Your password.." @bind-value="_user.Password" />
   <ValidationMessage For="@(() => @_user.Password)"></ValidationMessage>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <p><b>Email</b></p>
   <input id="email" class="solid" placeholder="you@example.com" @bind-value="_user.Email" />
   <ValidationMessage For="@(() => @_user.Email)"></ValidationMessage>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <p><b>Company</b></p>
   <input id="company" class="solid" placeholder="Your company.." @bind-value="_user.Company" />
   <ValidationMessage For="@(() => @_user.Company)"></ValidationMessage>
</div>


<br />

<button disabled="@loading" class="btn btn-primary">

   @if (loading)
   {
       <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
       <NavLink href="/login" class="btn btn-link">Register</NavLink>
   }
   Register
</button>
<NavLink href="/login" class="btn btn-link">Login</NavLink> </EditForm>
```

```
@code {
   private User _user = new User();
 
   private string StatusMessage;
   private string StatusClass;
 
   private bool loading;
 
 
   private void OnValidSubmit()
   {
       if (loading == true)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("You have successfully registered!");
       }
 
       else
       {
           loading = false;
           Console.WriteLine("Check your information again!");
       }
   }
 
   protected void HandleValidSubmit()
   {
       StatusClass = "alert-info";
       StatusMessage = " You have successfully registered! Please click the Login button to log in!";
   }
 
   protected void HandleInvalidSubmit()
   {
       StatusClass = "alert-danger";
       StatusMessage = " Check your information again!";
   } 
}
```

AppDbContext.cs:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
   public AppDbContext()
   {
   }

   public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
   {
   }

   protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
   {
       if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
       {
           optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=testblazor;Integrated
Security=True;");
       }
   }

   //protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   //{
   //    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   //    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
   //}

   public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Seems something went wrong with the formatting. Read about [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)). Remove all the `>` and format the code blocks as described in the linked help page.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and response.

Comment: @Katarina I've edited your post to enhance legibility. Please check it and amend it if needed.

Comment: You need to add a clearer description of the problem you're having. The question should not be entirely within your title, that should be just a summary before providing more details of where you're stuck exactly. A code dump doesn't provide that on its own. Https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask